# Economy command: Not allowing users to give money to themselves

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to send a message when a user mentions themselves in the command.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const db = require("quick.db")
const client = new Discord.Client();
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    let user = message.mentions.users.first();
    if(!user) return message.reply("Si no mencionas a alguien para darle dinero, no podre hacer nada.")
    let dinerodado = args.slice(1).join(" ")
    if(!dinerodado) return message.reply("Si no me dices la cantidad de dinero que le quieres dar a alguien, no podre hacer nada tampoco.")
      
    db.add(`user.balance`, dinerodado)
    message.channel.send(`✅ La cantidad de **${dinerodado}$** fue enviada a **${user}** perfectamente.`)
}
```

Comment: So, how do prevent two people from teaming up and giving each another other unlimited money? I think the concept is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want people to give money to themselves, you could put

```
if(user.id === message.author.id) return;
if(!user) return message.reply("Si no mencionas a alguien para darle dinero, no podre hacer nada.")
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to prevent that is to add this code at the top:

```js
if (user.id === message.author.id) return("You can't give money to yourself!"); // ¡No puedes darte dinero a ti mismo!
```